# Set response header for every endpoint under a specific resource

Tags: java, httpresponse, response-headers

I want to set the following response header for all endpoints under a specific resource:

```
cache-control: no-cache
```

For example, I have the resource called "example", and under example there are multiple endpoints such as "test1" and "test2". So the url's would look like this:

> localhost:4000/example/test1

and

> localhost:4000/example/test2

Instead of setting the response cache-control header individually on test1 and test2, is there a way to set it at the example level (resource level)? Currently, under test1 and test2 I am using the following code to set the response header:

```
CacheControl lCacheControl = new CacheControl();
lCacheControl.setNoCache(true);
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(lOutput).cacheControl(lCacheControl).build();
```

The code is written in java.

Comment: Possibly with a post-process filter: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/interceptingfilter-142169.html